# Pandas Keep Every Other Group of Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So say I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
4  13  14  15
5  16  17  18
```

And I'd like to keep every other group of two rows, ie the end result looks like this:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
4  13  14  15
5  16  17  18
```

I know how to get alternating rows using df.iloc[::2] but that gives me:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
2   7   8   9
4  13  14  15
```

Be great if someone could point me in the right direction here, not sure if it's possible to do this with iloc but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this -- one would be to note that in a repeating pattern of 4 you want the first two, or:

```
In [18]: df.loc[np.arange(len(df)) % 4 < 2]
Out[18]: 
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
4  13  14  15
5  16  17  18
```

because

```
In [19]: np.arange(len(df))
Out[19]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [20]: np.arange(len(df)) % 4
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1])

In [21]: np.arange(len(df)) % 4 < 2
Out[21]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. Say I wanted to do this in groups of 24, am I correct in thinking that I would do %48 < 24?

Comment: Yep!  Also extends naturally to more complex cases.

Answer (score 4):

Let's use a little math and boolean indexing:

```
df[(df.index // 2 % 2) == 0]
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
4  13  14  15
5  16  17  18
```

Comment: This works exactly as it should, if I wanted to do it with groups of 24 would I just replace both 2's with 24?

Comment: @JSolomonCulp df[(df.index // 24 % 2) == 0]

Comment: I really like the flexibility of DSM's solution. df[(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 24 % 2) == 0]